# Free screen recorder with no watermark/limit

Tags: windows, screen-recording

I'm looking for a screen recorder that meets the following requirements:

1. Free.
2. Record and screenshot:
   3a. Normal desktop and games (particularly Steam ones).
   3b. Full screen or a manual selection.
3. No watermark.
4. No time limit.
5. Good quality, standard, small output files.
6. Easy to use.

I've read into many (Bandicam, Dxtory, etc) and only OBS comes close but it can't screenshot and selecting a section to record is way too difficult.

Answer (score 6):

[ShareX](https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX) is what I am using at work for screnshots / screen recording.

**Pros**

- It's open source
- Capture in png / mp4
- I never met any limitation

**Cons**

- Offers a lot of options (editors, uploaders, ...), it took me a little time to figure out how to make it match my needs
- I never tried it in games nor Steam

Comment: Wow, I am very impressed with ShareX to the point where I'm considering replacing Greenshot, Fireshot, and OBS but it's a real shame that it doesn't support (only Steam?) games and, as of 2015, the developers had no interest in doing so.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend [ScreenToGif](http://www.screentogif.com/). While it has some downsides it's a free tool which is extremely easy to use.

**Pros:**

- It's free without a watermark
- Easy to install and use
- It now can capture the whole screen (experimental)
- I never hit a time limit
- You have basic editor tools
- Outputs as gif, avi-file or png

**Cons:**

- Video files are extremely large you would need some working for the parameters to fit your needs
- Don't know for sure if it works with steam games